# How to prevent drag and drop if the node is not null [C#]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop

I have a problem with drag and drop on game. I want to block user if he is dragging the object from down to up in case they have sticks in same angles. if they dont so it is ok. But if they have even one stick in same direction so stick should go back to down to first position.

I am lost a bit. Can you help please :)

here is the code where I drag and drop also rotation...

[Here on the pic generated stick group can fit only 1. and 3. places.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELdli.png)

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InputController : MonoBehaviour
{

```
float clickTime;
RaycastHit2D rayhit;
float smallestDistance = 1.5f;
int smallestId = 1;
public Transform[] nodes;
public LayerMask selectableObjLayerMask;


void Update()
{


    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {

        clickTime = Time.time;
        rayhit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero, Mathf.Infinity, selectableObjLayerMask);
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        if (rayhit)
        {
            if (Time.time - clickTime < .2f)
            {
                Node node = rayhit.transform.GetComponent<Node>();
                if (node != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < node.sticks.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Vector3 newAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, (node.sticks[i].transform.localEulerAngles.z - 45));
                        newAngles.z = newAngles.z < 0 ? newAngles.z + 180 : newAngles.z;
                        newAngles.z = newAngles.z >180 ? newAngles.z - 180 : newAngles.z;
                        node.sticks[i].transform.localEulerAngles = newAngles;

                        node.sticks[i].degree = (int)newAngles.z;
                        Debug.Log(i + " = " + node.sticks[i].degree);


                    }

                }
            }
            else 
            {
                Node currNode = rayhit.transform.GetComponent<Node>();
                if(currNode.isMoved == false)
                {
                    smallestId = 0;
                    smallestDistance = 999;
                    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Length; i++)
                    {

                        float distance = Vector2.Distance(rayhit.transform.position, nodes[i].transform.position);
                        if (smallestDistance > distance)
                        {
                            smallestDistance = distance;
                            smallestId = i;

                            Debug.Log("Obje : " + currNode);
                        }
                    }

                    rayhit.transform.position = nodes[smallestId].transform.position;
                    if (rayhit.transform.parent != nodes[smallestId].transform)
                    { 
                        if (nodes[smallestId].transform.childCount > 0 && nodes[smallestId].transform != rayhit.transform.parent)
                        {
                            if (currNode != null)
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < currNode.sticks.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    nodes[smallestId].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Node>().sticks.Add(currNode.sticks[i]);
                                    currNode.sticks[i].transform.SetParent(nodes[smallestId].transform.GetChild(0));
                                }
                                Destroy(rayhit.transform.gameObject);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (currNode != null)
                            {
                                currNode.isMoved = true;
                            }
                            rayhit.transform.SetParent(nodes[smallestId].transform);
                        }
                    }

                }

            }               

        }
        rayhit = new RaycastHit2D();

    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        if(rayhit.transform != null)
        {
            Node currNode = rayhit.transform.GetComponent<Node>();
            if(currNode != null)
                if (currNode.isMoved == false)
                {
                    if (Time.time - clickTime >= 0.2f)
                    {
                        Vector2 newPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
                        rayhit.transform.position = newPos;
                    }
                }
        }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem? How i this specifically related to Visual-Studio? ... Just in general: You should store and reuse the results of `GetComponent` and not re-get it every frame ...

Comment: I haven't tried something exactly because I could not solve exactly how I can get the directions of node 1,2,3 and generated node too. But I could not find a way to compare them exactly. I guess I should check every two nodes in two loops. But I cant clarify :\
btw i added visual studio by mistake i deleted it again.